# skipping the header from java map reduce code

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to get the summary of a csv file and the first line of the file is the header. Is there a way to make the values of each column with its header name as key value pair from the Java code.

Eg: Input file is like

A,B,C,D

1,2,3,4

5,6,7,8

I want the the output from mapper as `(A,1),(B,2),(C,3),(D,4),(A,5),....`

Note:I tried using overriding the run function in the Mapper class to skip the first line. But As far as I know the run function gets called for each input split and is thus not suiting my need. Any help on this will really be appreciated.

This is the way my mapper looks:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String line = value.toString();
        String[] splits = line.split(",",-1);
        int length = splits.length;
    //  count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            columnName.set(header[i]);      
            context.write(columnName, new Text(splits[i]+""));
        }

    }

    public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {        
        setup(context); 
        try 
        {

            if (context.nextKeyValue())
            { 

                Text columnHeader = context.getCurrentValue();
                header =  columnHeader.toString().split(",");

            }    
            while (context.nextKeyValue()) 
            {
                map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
            }
        } 
        finally 
        {
            cleanup(context);
        }      
    }
```

Comment: what will be the exit when file is `A,B,C,1,2` ??? also, show us your tries with `Mapper` class, does not seems a bad approach and maybe we can find the mistake

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to skip the first line? Or you want to map header names to its values?

Comment: I have added the mapper class.. I basically want to map header names to values..Sorry if i was not clear

Comment: @Jordi Castilla.. I am sorry.. I didn't get you!

Comment: if there are more numbers than chars you start over (`A5`) what happens in the opposite case? in my example (`A,B,C 1,2`) last element would be (`C1`) ???

Comment: No.. Thats not the case..  Its a clean csv data file.. i.e. number of values are same as number of chars. Every line contains same number of elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the column headers are alphabets and column values are numbers.

One of the ways to achieve this, is to use `DistributedCache`.
Following are the steps:

1. Create a file containing the column headers.
2. In the Driver code, add this file to the distributed cache, by calling `Job::addCacheFile()`
3. In the `setup()` method of the mapper, access this file from the distributed cache. Parse and store the contents of the file in a `columnHeader` list.
4. In the `map()` method, check if the values in each record match the headers (stored in `columnnHeader` list). If yes, then ignore that record (Because the record just contains the headers). If no, then emit the values along with the column headers.

This is how the Mapper and Driver code looks like:

**Driver:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "HeaderParser");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(HeaderParserMapper.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);

    job.addCacheFile(new URI("/in/header.txt#header.txt"));
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/in/in7.txt"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/out/"));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1);
}
```

**Driver Logic:**

- Copy "header.txt" (which contains just one line: A,B,C,D) to HDFS
- In the Driver, add "header.txt" to distributed cache, by executing following statement:

  ```
  job.addCacheFile(new URI("/in/header.txt#header.txt"));
  ```

**Mapper:**

```
public static class HeaderParserMapper
        extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text , Text, NullWritable>{

    String[] headerList;
    String header;

    @Override
    protected void setup(Mapper.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("header.txt"));
        header = bufferedReader.readLine();
        headerList = header.split(",");
    }

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String line = value.toString();
        String[] values = line.split(",");

        if(headerList.length == values.length && !header.equals(line)) {
            for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
                context.write(new Text(headerList[i] + "," + values[i]), NullWritable.get());
        }
    }
}
```

**Mapper Logic:**

- Override `setup()` method.
- Read "header.txt" (which was put in distributed cache in the Driver) in the `setup()` method.
- In the `map()` method, check if the line matches the header. If yes, then ignore that line. Else, output header and values as (h1,v1), (h2,v2), (h3,v3) and (h4,v4).

I ran this program on the following input:

```
A,B,C,D
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
```

I got the following output (where values are matched with respective header):

```
A,1
A,5
B,2
B,6
C,3
C,7
D,4
D,8
```

Comment: Sounds great.. Will surely try this out in my day.. Thanks alot for your time.. Is there a straight forward way to just skip the first line of the file?

Comment: I am not aware of any. Since, the first line could go to any mapper (assuming there are 'n' number of mappers). Best way is to use DistributedCache. If I try this out, I will post the code.

Comment: Nice. Parallel to setup(), do we have to implement any method like cleanup()?

Comment: No. In this case, cleanup() is not required. setup() and cleanup() serve different purposes and you use them based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer by @Manjunath Ballur works as a good hack. But, Map Reduce must be used in conjunction to simplicity. Checking the header for each line is not the recommended way to do this.

One way to go is to write a custom [InputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html) that does this work for you